# How to compare two linear non-nested models with Voung test?

Tags: r, testing, compare, comparison

I want to compare two linear non-nested models, for example:

```
data(longley)
attach(longley)
r1<-glm(GNP~Unemployed+Armed.Forces+Population, family=gaussian)
r2<-glm(GNP~Unemployed+Armed.Forces+Employed, family=gaussian)
```

However, I get this error:

```
vuong(r1, r2)
Error in vuong(r1, r2) : 
  your object of class glm is unsupported by predprob.glmyour object of class lm is unsupported by predprob.glm
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should add a reproducible example to your post.

Comment: edited. Models lacking any sense but 100% reproducible and representative of my problem.

Comment: From where is `vuong` function?

Comment: It's from pscl package

Comment: Did you read the help page? It is clearly written `an object inheriting from class glm, negbin or zeroinfl`. `r1` and `r2` are of class `lm`.

Comment: Changed to glm. What now?

Comment: looking at the guts of `pscl:::predprob.glm` (which is where the proximal problem occurs), it looks like it's hard-coded to accept only negbin/Poisson/binomial models.  It could probably be hacked.  In the meantime, does `library("sos"); findFn("vuong")` turn up any useful alternatives?

Comment: It seems that functions "voung" and "clarke" from package "games" support the lm estimates! And they work in my case, thank you! I only wonder if the results of the test would be more precise if I used different estimation method (not lm) and different package. What do you think?

Comment: You should use whatever estimation method/model makes sense for your data and question ... You can write up your solution (use `games::vuong()` instead) as an answer to your own question ...

Comment: No easy answers, huh?:) Thanks, maybe one day I'll write something on my own.

Comment: The `nonnest2` package provides an object-oriented implementation `vuongtest()` which seems to be more general than the `pscl` implementation. Also, you may consider other tests for non-nested models, e.g., `encomptest()`, `jtest()` and `coxtest()` in the `lmtest` package.